# BootstrapValidator plugin just reloads the page after form is submitted

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use AJAX form submit with BootstrapValidator but when I press the button it just refreshes the page. Here is the code that I am using:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#call').bootstrapValidator({
    fields: {
        your: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please enter your phone number'
                 },
                digits: {
                    message: 'Please enter a valid phone number'
                }
            }
        },
       frnd: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please enter a  phone number'
                },
                digits: {
                    message: 'Please enter a valid phone number'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   })
.on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(e.target);
    var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');
    $.post("sendCall.php", $form.serialize(), function (response) {
        $('#alert').html(response);
      });
   });
 });
</script>
```

Ofcourse, I have included all the required jQuery and plugin files. The submit button I have is:

```
<button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-success">Connect</button>
```

I have tried removing 'type=submit' and then it does nothing after button is pressed (it doesn't even reloads the page).

```
<button id="form-submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

The form id is 'call'. Firebug isn't showing any errors on the console. What am I doing wrong?

**Update** here is the entire html: http://pastebin.com/D846AkHy

Comment: Can you please post you entire HTML file?

Comment: Sure, just a minute @bumbu

Comment: @bumbu Here it is http://pastebin.com/D846AkHy

Comment: also define  `.on('error.form.bv', function(e) {}` when there's an error `e.preventDefault();` will not be called and your page reloads.

Comment: @Bass Jobsen Can you pls give an example?

Comment: see: http://bootstrapvalidator.com/settings/#event-validator